# Processing: Library for Complex numbers?

Tags: java, math, processing, complex-numbers

I've just started learning Processing and I'm curious if there is a library for modeling complex numbers of the form *`a + bi`*. Particularly one that can handle multiplication of complex numbers numbers like:

```
(a + bi)(a + bi)
```

Comment: @TonyHopkinson No, not broken, just yielding poor results. Processing suffers a pretty horribly non-Google-able name. The only links turning up on forums are now dead. "complex numbers processing", "processing complex numbers library". You can see how these queries would yield poor results.

Comment: I've actually created my own library for complex numbers.  Well, pseudo library. You can't import it, but you can copy paste it into a new tab of any sketch you want.  I can send you some source code if you want. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write your own class in java or be inspired by [this class](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/Complex.java.html). Also you can import classic java libraries like [common-math](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/).

If you need only multiplication just add this class to your sketch:

```
class Complex {
    double real;   // the real part
    double img;   // the imaginary part

    public Complex(double real, double img) {
        this.real = real;
        this.img = img;
    }

    public Complex multi(Complex b) {
        double real = this.real * b.real - this.img * b.img;
        double img = this.real * b.img + this.img * b.real;
        return new Complex(real, img);
    }
}
```

And then simple use for you example:

```
Complex first = new Complex(a, b);
complex result =  first.multi(first);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Qscript library handles complex numbers add, subtract, powers the shebang.
You can add it from the GUI add library function